# How to determine if events are mutually independent.

Tags: probability

Consider the experiment of tossing three coins. Let A be an event of getting head on the first coin, B be an event of getting tail on the second coin, and C be an event of getting at least two heads.

Which of the events here are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical example to show that pairwise independence
(between A & B, B & C, A & C) does not imply independence, which would also require $P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C).$ The latter does $not$
hold here, because $A \cap B$ implies $C$.